# $and query returns no result

Tags: mongodb

Ok this one is killing me.  Maybe its late and I am forgetting something, but this should work.

For test purposes, I have about 6000 documents in my collection.  There is a property called `Priority` which has a value of 2 in every instance.

The following two queries each return **all** 6000 documents:

```
{
    Priority: {
        $gt: 1
    }
}
```

and

```
{
    Priority: {
        $lt: 10
    }
}
```

This query, however, returns 0 results and according to the Explain, does a full scan of all 6000 documents:

```
{
$and: [
        {
            Priority: {
                $gt: 1
            }
        },
        {
            Priority: {
                $lt: 10
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Have I missed something?

Comment: Once again, a user with less than 100 points trolls the internet leaving useless comments and contributing nothing.  Of course I read the documentation. Thanks for your help, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I said, "I need someone with a car that can seat four people and a car that can seat at least eight people", someone with a single car that sat eight people would not ordinarily be understood to qualify. Your *and* query can only be satisfied by an entry with *two* values for Priority, one less than 10 and one greater than 1.

The [docs for *and*](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24and) have a link to the [multikey semantics](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Multikeys) of mongoDB.

Comment: Ok - its a bit misleading, but I understand what you are saying.  I simplified my actual problem in this question, expecting a different answer.  I might just create a new question, more detailed.  Thanks.

Comment: In case you can help, I've posted a follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767747/combine-two-or-statements

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `$and` here.

Instead you can rewrite your query like this:

```
{Priority: {$gt: 1, $lt: 10}}
```