# Combine two $or statements

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to perform a query which is composed of two `$or`'s:

```
|--------------------
| Date1  |  Date2   |
|--------------------
| NULL   |  NULL    | *
| NULL   |  TODAY   | *
| NULL   |  TOMRW   | 
| TODAY  |  TODAY   | *
| TODAY  |  NULL    | *
| TOMRW  |  NULL    | 
|--------------------
```

(I've marked the rows that would match with an asterisk)

```
(Date1 == null || Date1 <= today) && (Date2 == null || Date2 <= today)
```

I am not sure how to express this query in MongoDB.

It can be broken down into two individual queries that do exactly what they should:

```
{
    "$or": [{
        "Date1": {
            "$exists": false
        }
    },
    {
        "Date1": {
            "$exists": true,
            "$lte": new Date("2012-01-07T04:45:52.057Z")
        }
    }]
}
```

and

```
{
    "$or": [{
        "Date2": {
            "$exists": false
        }
    },
    {
        "Date2": {
            "$exists": true,
            "$lte": new Date("2012-01-07T04:45:52.057Z")
        }
    }]
}
```

Both of these select the correct set of documents - I just dont know how to execute them as a single query.

My initial thought was to do a query like this:

```
{
    $and: [orQuery1, orQuery2]
}
```

Using an `$and` query returns 0 results.  It was explained why here in this thread: [$and query returns no result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767484/and-query-returns-no-result)

Also in that thread, a suggestion was made to do a query like this:

```
{
    Key: {valToMatch1: 1, valToMatch2: 2}
}
```

But I dont think an `$or` can be executed this way.

So, the question is: How do I construct my query such that I can combine the two $or's into a single query?

(Its getting very late so I hope this question makes sense.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
use test
db.test.insert({a:1})
db.test.insert({a:2, Date2:new Date("01/07/2012")})
db.test.insert({a:3, Date2:new Date("01/08/2012")})
db.test.insert({a:4, Date1:new Date("01/07/2012"), Date2:new Date("01/07/2012")})
db.test.insert({a:5, Date1:new Date("01/07/2012")})
db.test.insert({a:6, Date1:new Date("01/08/2012")})
```

first subquery
    db.test.distinct('a', {...});

> [1, 2, 3]

second subquery
    db.test.distinct('a', {...});

> [ 1, 5, 6 ]

```
(Date1 == null || Date1 <= today) && (Date2 == null || Date2 <= today)
```

unwind

```
Date1 == null && Date2 == null ||
Date1 == null && Date2 <= today ||
Date1 <= today && Date2 == null ||
Date1 <= today && Date2 <= today ||
```

query

```
db.test.find(
{
  $or : 
  [
    {$and: [
        {"Date1": {"$exists": false}},
        {"Date2": {"$exists": false}}
      ]},
    {$and: [
        {"Date1": {"$exists": false}},
        {"Date2": {
            "$exists": true,
            "$lte": new Date("2012-01-07T04:45:52.057Z")}
        }
      ]},
    {$and: [
        {"Date2": {"$exists": false}},
        {"Date1": {
            "$exists": true,
            "$lte": new Date("2012-01-07T04:45:52.057Z")}
        }
      ]},
    {$and: [
        {"Date2": {
            "$exists": true,
            "$lte": new Date("2012-01-07T04:45:52.057Z")}
        },
        {"Date1": {
            "$exists": true,
            "$lte": new Date("2012-01-07T04:45:52.057Z")}
        }
      ]}
  ]
})
>[ 1 ]
```

this should work too (assume that 'not exist' and 'null' is the same)

```
db.test.find(
{
  $and : 
  [
    {$or: [
        {"Date1": null},
        {"Date1": { "$lte": new Date("2012-01-07T04:45:52.057Z")} }
      ]},
    {$or: [
        {"Date2": null},
        {"Date2": { "$lte": new Date("2012-01-07T04:45:52.057Z")} }
      ]}
  ]
}
)
```

Comment: Hmml.. this is an interesting approach.  I havent thought of my query like this.  I am going to try it and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for helping me open my mind to a different way to construct this query.  Your solution does satisfy my requirements, though I suspect your query becomes much more complicated as additional or's are needed.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem lies not in the logic composition. Your nested `$and` `$or` query is perfectly fine.

It's the difference between MongoDB and JavaScript on creating a date that baffles you.

in Mongo:

```
> new Date("2012-01-07T04:45:52.057Z")
ISODate("0NaN-NaN-NaNTNaN:NaN:NaNZ")
```

in JavaScript:

```
> new Date("2012-01-07T04:45:52.057Z")
Sat, 07 Jan 2012 04:45:52 GMT
```

To fix it, you should use `ISODate` in mongo.

```
> ISODate('2012-01-07T04:45:52.057Z')
ISODate("2012-01-07T04:45:52.057Z")
```

**UPDATE**: append tests:

to prove the correctness of your logic combination, I wrote the following scripts:

`populate.js`: populate your sampling data:

```
var past = new Date('01/01/2011'),
    future = new Date('01/01/2013');

var dates = [
  {
    num: 1
  },
  {
    num: 2,
    Date2: past
  },
  {
    num: 3,
    Date2: future
  },
  {
    num: 4,
    Date1: past,
    Date2: past
  },
  {
    num: 5,
    Date1: past
  },
  {
    num: 6,
    Date1: future
  }
];

dates.forEach(function(date) {
  db.dates.insert(date);
});
```

`query.js`: test the three queries:

```
function queryNum(query) {
  print(db.dates.find(query).map(function(v) {
    return v.num;
  }));
}

var q1 = {
  "$or": [{
    "Date1": {
      "$exists": false
    }
  },
  {
    "Date1": {
      "$exists": true,
      "$lte": new Date('01/01/2012')
    }
  }]
};

var q2 = {
  "$or": [{
    "Date2": {
      "$exists": false
    }
  },
  {
    "Date2": {
      "$exists": true,
      "$lte": new Date('01/01/2012')
    }
  }]
};

var q3 = {
  $and: [q1, q2]
};

queryNum(q1);
queryNum(q2); 
queryNum(q3);
```

It properly prints:

```
1,2,3,4,5
2,2,4,5,6
1,2,4,5
```

Comment: No the problem is definitely not the dates, as I said the queries work independent of one another exactly as intended.  They only stop working when grouped inside an $and query.

Comment: @BryanMigliorisi I wrote tests to prove the correctness of your original logic combination, see the updated answer.