# Mongodb $and returns no results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

This is a similar question to [$and query returns no result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767484/and-query-returns-no-result), however the answer there does not apply in this case.

I have the following query:

```
{
  $and: [
    {
      ownerId: "505b832c975a5c3ca6e9523b"
    },
    {
      privacyLevel: "Public"
    }
  ]
}
```

My collection has 16 documents, all of which are "Public" and 7 of which have the ownerId above. The subqueries behave correctly and return the correct documents so I would expect 7 results from this query.

The $and query returns nothing, I am at a loss as to why that might be.

Comment: Mongodb version? Also is that the full query your are running or just part of it that causes problem?

Comment: Mongodb 2.0 (I don't have more detail since this is running on Jelastic and I haven't found the patch version number.) Yes this is the full query.

Comment: Propviding the server is 2.0 this should work, but there is nothing wrong with your syntax, its odd that your using a objectid in string form but apart from that not much else

Comment: If, somehow, this wasn't server 2.0, presumably there would be a nasty error about $and not be recognized in the logs?

Comment: Not sure, since $and was since 1.9 and I havent had this question in a while I have forgotten what it does, I think it should though

Comment: As I recall, you don't get an error when using `$and` pre-2.0 because it just looks like a property named `$and` which doesn't exist in any docs.

Comment: Are your ownerId's stored as Strings or ObjectId's in the actual database?

Comment: The ownerId field is stored as a String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just querying two fields you do not need an $and operator. Your query will simply be:

```
.find({ownerId: "505b832c975a5c3ca6e9523b", privacyLevel: "Public"})
```

Comment: That works, but due to my use of Datanucleus to create the queries, I don't think I can remove the "$and".

Comment: Are you using JDO or JPA for your db interface?

Comment: I'm using JDO for my interface.

Comment: Switched to morphia and used this approach.